# ¿como comparar dos arrays?

Tags: java, array, jframe

tengo dos arreglos, uno de tipo String y otro de tipo double, y estoy trabajando con una interfaz visual, necesito rastrear de una lista de empleados cual tiene el mayor salario y mostrarlo, ordene el arreglo donde estan guardados los salarios (el de tipo double) con el metodo burbuja ahora ¿como hago que el nombre acompañe a su salario?, el nombre esta guardado en el arreglo de tipo String le muestro lo que llevo de la interfaz visaul y el del codigo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les dejo aqui mi codigo y el metodo burbuja

```
     String[]nombres1=new String[10];
        for (int i=0; i <lista_nombres.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
        String s=lista_nombres.getModel().getElementAt(i);
        nombres1[i]=s;
      
    
    }
        
         double[]numeros=new double[10];
        
 
    for (int i=0; i <lista_salario.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
        String s=lista_salario.getModel().getElementAt(i);
        numeros[i]=Double.parseDouble(s);
    }
        
         for(int i=0; i < numeros.length-1; i++){
       for(int j=0; j < numeros.length-1; j++){
           if(numeros[j] < numeros[j+1]){
               double tmp = numeros[j+1];
               numeros[j+1]=numeros[j];
               numeros[j]=tmp;
           }
       }
   }
```

rico.addElement(nombres1[0] + numeros[0]);

```
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias ya lo corrijo

Comment: Cuando tenes dos array que en resumidas cuentas funcionan como uno, al ordenar por uno, tambien hace los cambios en las posiciones del otro...

Comment: @gbianchi y como puedo hacer que mis arrays funcionen como uno, es que creo que cada uno funciona por su parte, lo unico que tienen en comun es que antes de que se de el ordenamiento en el array de tipo double , el array de tipo duble y el de tipo String comparten posiciones (el nombre con el salario al que corresponde) ya que se agreagan al mismo tiempo, pero cuando hago el ordenamiento en el de tipo double, la cantidad mas alta sube a la posicion 0 del arreglo, pero en el array de tipo nombre no cambia por lo que el nombre ya no coincide con el salario

Comment: Es justamente lo que te estoy diciendo.. si los cargas al mismo tiempo, "funcionan" como si fueran uno solo.. cuando ordenas, vos moves dos elementos de posicion en uno... entonces lo unico que tenes que hacer, es mover al mismo tiempo de posicion en el otro ;)

Comment: @gbianchi hay algun metodo de ordenamiento para arrays de tipo String? es que el metodo burbuja no creo que me funcione ¿verdad?

Comment: el metodo burbuja ordena cualquier cosa.. siempre y cuando sean cosas comparables.. y los strings lo son.. pero esa no es la respuesta... si no entendes lo que tenes que hacer, que ya esta TODO en tu codigo, te pongo una respuesta.. pero no debes ordenar el array de strings...

Comment: @gbianchi Perdon soy muy nuevo en esto, aun no entiendo muy bien que es lo que debo hacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java proporciona clases y metodos que ayudan con las tareas mas básicas, para ello, java creó las colecciones. Con ellos, un método de ordenamiento estático para ordenar en base a un elemento del objeto que contiene la lista, para comenzar, creas un objeto `Empleado` que contenga el nombre y el salario, seguidamente, creas sus métodos get y set para acceder a ellos.

```
public class Empleado {

    private String nombre;
    private Double salario;

    public Empleado(String nombre, Double salario) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Empleado{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", salario=" + salario + '}';
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(Double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

}
```

Una vez creado el objeto creas un listado agregando los objetos a la lista con `list.add()`, y por ultimo, usas la clase `Collections` para ordenar el listado;

```
List<Empleado> empleados = new ArrayList();
    empleados.add(new Empleado("Carlos septimo", 1500D));
    empleados.add(new Empleado("Luis de Magallanez", 1200D));
    empleados.add(new Empleado("Juan Esculia", 1300D));
    empleados.add(new Empleado("Arelio Hernandez", 1900D));
    empleados.add(new Empleado("Cristina Falcon", 800D));

    Collections.sort(empleados, new Comparator<Empleado>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Empleado o1, Empleado o2) {
            return o2.getSalario().compareTo(o1.getSalario());
        }
    });
    System.out.println("El trabajador que mas gana es " + empleados.get(0));
```

salida por consola

```
El trabajador que mas gana es Empleado{nombre=Arelio Hernandez, salario=1900.0}
```

para crear los `array` para llenar los listados del `form` usas un `for` para llenar los `array`;

```
    String[] nombres = new String[empleados.size()];
    Double[] salarios = new Double[empleados.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < empleados.size(); i++) {
        nombres[i] = empleados.get(i).getNombre();
        salarios[i] = empleados.get(i).getSalario();
    }
```